# Foreign Key settings with regards to bridging tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a question on foreign key settings with regards to bridging tables. I still am unsure of how the deletion process works. My foreign keys are currently all set to On Delete: No Action, so does that mean that in the case of a bridging table, in order to delete records in one or both of the parent tables, I would have to delete the records they feature in in the bridging table first or does it work differently with many-to-many relationships? Apologies if this is a simple, dumb question but it seems pretty difficult for someone new to databases to find clear, simple, easy-to-follow documentation anywhere to explain these things.

Comment: You cannot delete a parent if there is a child. It follows then that you  delete the child before you delete the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is pretty straightforward:

You can't delete a row if some other row exists that references the one you want to delete.

Example: A college photography course is created as a row in the `courses` table.

```
INSERT INTO courses SET course_id = 1234, title = 'Photography';
```

People enroll in the course:

```
INSERT INTO enrollments SET course_id = 1234, student_id = 9877;
INSERT INTO enrollments SET course_id = 1234, student_id = 9876;
INSERT INTO enrollments SET course_id = 1234, student_id = 9875;
```

Then the instructor wants to cancel the course.

```
DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_id = 1234;
```

This is blocked, because there are rows in `enrollments` that reference the row in `courses`.

Likewise, a student may want to withdraw from school this semester. They try to remove their record:

```
DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id = 9877;
```

This is blocked, because the student is still enrolled in the photography class.

The `enrollments` class is a bridging table (I call these intersection tables, but there's no official terminology for these types of tables). It is basically a pair of foreign key columns, which reference the respective tables `courses` and `students`.

The foreign key constraints in `enrollments` require that each of the referenced rows in the other two tables exist. You can't delete either the `courses` row or the `students` row while there's an enrollment that references it.

The way to handle this is to delete the dependent row (the one that has the foreign key constraint) before you delete the referenced row.

The optional `ON DELETE CASCADE` syntax makes a foreign key constraint handle this automatically. That is, deleting a row in `courses` would automatically delete any rows that reference the course. If you don't use this option, then trying to delete the course returns an error.